# WSDL endpoint in wso2 Enterprise Service Bus

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I'm running wso2 and wanted to know which config file should i modify to change the wsdl endpoint. I have created a proxy service which redirects request to backend service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ca find the configured end points in synapse configuration [in case you don't refer them from the inbuilt registry].

You can change the configuration from the UI.

Manage --> Service Bus --> Source View

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can change it from address tag within endpoints in synapse configuration